# grep to $URL then sed $URL

Tags: sed, grep

I have in 1.txt:

```
https://www.google.se/
https://www.bing.com/
```

```
URL=$(grep ".*" ./1.txt) | sed "s/$/\">${URL}/" ./1.txt > ./2.txt
```

I get in 2.txt:

```
https://www.google.se/">
https://www.bing.com/">
```

I want in 2.txt:

```
https://www.google.se/">https://www.google.se/
https://www.bing.com/">https://www.bing.com/
```

Comment: Use code formatting, please: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: `sed 's/.*/&">&/' 1.txt`

Comment: Do you want that in 2.txt because you then have another step afterwards to finally get it into the format you really want in the end? It just looks suspiciously like some intermediate format.

Comment: How about `paste -d "" 2.txt 1.txt` -- given your sample files, that's all you need.

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be any reason to store the data in a variable.

```
awk -v OFS='">' '{ print $0, $0 }' 1.txt >2.txt
```

This would do what you seem to want to do, which is to insert the two characters `">` at the end of each line, followed by the original contents of the line.  In this code, this is done by outputting the line as twe new fields.  The output field separator, `OFS`, will be inserted between these automatically.  The value of `OFS` is set to `">` on the command line.

Alternatively, using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/\1">\1/' 1.txt >2.txt
```

This uses a capturing group to capture the whole line.  This is then replaced with the captured bit, the string `">`, and the captured bit again.

As pointed out in comments, an even shorter variant would be

```
sed 's/.*/&">&/' 1.txt >2.txt
```

The `&`, when it occurs in the replacement part of the `s` command, will be replaced by the bit of the input matching the expression.  The expression is `.*`, so `&` would be the complete line, and `&">&` would insert the line twice with `">` in-between.

---

Your pipeline,

```
URL=$(grep ".*" ./1.txt) | sed "s/$/\">${URL}/" ./1.txt > ./2.txt
```

makes little sense, as the left and right hand side of it are executed independently of each other (and there is no communication between them).  The value `$URL` would be empty in the `sed` expression.

If you had used

```
URL=$(grep ".*" ./1.txt); sed "s/$/\">${URL}/" ./1.txt >./2.txt
```

which is the same as

```
URL=$(<./1.txt); sed "s/$/\">${URL}/" ./1.txt >./2.txt
```

the `sed` command would have tried to insert the full contents of the `$URL` variable (the whole of `1.txt`) at the end of each line.  It would also have failed, since that value contains several `/` characters that would have interfered with the `/` delimiters of the `s` command.

Comment: Of course the first `sed` command can be simplified to ```sed 's/.*/&">&/'```.